# Issues with booting a custom Kali Linux Live USB on computers with Secure Boot

Tags: kali-linux, uefi, boot-loader, live-usb, secure-boot

As a project for a portable copy of my VM workspace and for later use in recovering dead drives (my main laptop is a 2015 model so data rescue is something to be concerned about), I’m trying to create a Kali Linux live usb that will boot on any x86 machine.

I created my ISO according to [the Kali documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/kali-linux-live-usb-install/) and flashed it with Etcher, but it’s unfortunately not signed to run under Secure Boot (which means I can’t just pop it into any computer and boot like I want to). Thus, I set out to find a way to sign it for secure boot or otherwise make it run without needing to disable it, but I’ve hit a dead end.

What I’ve tried (reflashing before each, and sometimes creating a new image with added packages):

- Selecting the USB device as a boot device, gives ‘the selected boot image failed to authenticate’
- Selecting to boot from EFI file and selecting either `bootia32.efi` or `boota64.efi` in `EFI\boot`, gives the same error
- installing shim-signed on the VM, creating a new image, reflashing, and trying the two previous methods, same error
- modifying the boot partition of the flashed device from the previous method to accommodate the three `*.efi.signed` files found in `usr\lib\shim` on the VM, booting from `shimia32.efi.signed` gives ‘boot device failed’, the other two fail to authenticate
- renaming various efi files to `fbia32.efi` (as in ‘follow bootloader’, the thing that shim calls) and/or `grubia32.efi` in an attempt to make shim’s efi find and call them, still gives ‘boot device failed’

What I’d like to try:

- Fedora’s version of shim as suggested in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1427535/how-to-manually-sign-kali-for-uefi), but the link is dead and I can’t find it on Fedora’s website
- [SuperUEFIinSecureBoot Disk](https://github.com/ValdikSS/Super-UEFIinSecureBoot-Disk), but I’m unsure how to merge that ISO’s bootloader with my custom image
- Linux Foundation Preloader, but I can’t find documentation

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this?